# Url parameters into url after htaccess redirection

Tags: .htaccess, url, parameters, double, redirect

I search over the web for this particular problem and didn't find any good answer. Here is my problem:

When I try this link:

[www.lempreintedutemps.com/fr/antiquite.html](http://www.lempreintedutemps.com/fr/antiquite.html)

It correctly redirect to the .../fr/antiquites.html... portion of the website but add all the parameters at the end. I would like them to not appear in the url.

Here is a portion of the .htacces code I use for the site:

```
RewriteEngine on

redirect permanent /fr/antiquite.html http://www.lempreintedutemps.com/fr/antiquites.html


rewritecond $1 \.(gif¦jpg¦css¦xml)$ [OR]

rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]

rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

rewriterule ^(.*) - [S=12] 

RewriteCond %{Request_URI} !^.*/fckeditor/.*
RewriteCond %{Request_URI} !^.*/catalogue/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html /index.php?lang=$1&type=$2&cat=autre [L]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean you want them to not appear? Do you want them completely gone, or do you just not want them to show up in the URL bar?

Comment: Sorry it wasn't that clear! I don't want them to show in the url. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly found the problem, I should never use both redirect permanent and RewriteRule. 
Instead of

```
redirect permanent /fr/antiquite.html http://www.lempreintedutemps.com/fr/antiquites.html
```

I used:

```
RewriteRule ^fr/antiquite.html http://www.lempreintedutemps.com/fr/antiquites.html [R=301,L]
```

And now everything is working.